# Entity Framework class instantiation behavior

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am facing a problem where my entity framework keeps behaving weirdly when I try to instantiate any class. I am trying to use the default **usermanager** behaviour to store data in my database. Once I start instantiating a new notification before it adds that notification to the list of notifications available in the application user class it persists those changes and process an error from entity framework saying that there is a multiplicity problem, how can I tell entity framework to not persist changes once I instantiate a class cf here is my controller code :

```
public string AddFriend(string AddedUserId)
{
    var AddedUser = UserManager.FindById(AddedUserId);
    var AddingUser = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    var friendship = new Friend(AddingUser, AddedUser) { IsInvitation = true };
    AddingUser.Friends.Add(friendship);
    AddedUser.Notifications.Add(new Notification(AddingUser, "Friend Invitation", 
                   "The user " + AddingUser.FirstName + " " + AddingUser.LastName + 
                   " Sent you a friend invitation", friendship));
    UserManager.Update(AddedUser);
    UserManager.Update(AddingUser);
    return "Friend was added successfully";
}
```

my Notification class :

```
[Table("Notifications")]
public class Notification
{
    [Key]
    public int NotificationId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public ApplicationUser AssociatedUser { get; set; }
    public Friend AssociatedFrienship { get; set; }
    public GroupMember AssociatedGroup { get; set; }
    public ChannelMember AssociatedChannel { get; set; }
    public Message AssociatedMessage { get; set; }
    public bool Consulted { get; set; }

    public Notification()
    {
    }

    public Notification(ApplicationUser associatedUser, string title, string content, Friend associatedFriend = null, GroupMember associatedGroup = null, ChannelMember associatedChannel = null, Message associatedMessage = null)
    {
        AssociatedUser = associatedUser;
        Title = title;
        Content = content;
        AssociatedChannel = associatedChannel;
        AssociatedGroup = associatedGroup;
        AssociatedFrienship = associatedFriend;
        AssociatedMessage = associatedMessage;
        Consulted = false;
    }
}
```

my ApplicationUser class:

```
public partial class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual List<Notification> Notifications { get; set; }
}
```

my FluentAPI code :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Notification>()
            .HasRequired(c => c.AssociatedUser)
            .WithMany(c => c.Notifications);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Other things apart, try using `string interpolation` instead of `+` like this: `$"The user {AddingUser.FirstName} {AddingUser.LastName} Sent you a friend invitation"` Also instead of passing every single property to `ctor` you can use `Object Initialization` like this `new Notification{ AssociatedUser=<value>, Title = <value>}` and set desired properties.

Comment: Post up code for what this UserManager.FindById() is doing and where the dbContext is being initialized.

Comment: the userManager.FindById() is a default method of identity framework that is delivered by microsoft, the code of that class is available online. I don't really think that the problem comes from microsoft code, otherwhise it would be corcky to deliver a framework code that is messed up.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any foreign key to link `AssociatedUser`. Try adding a property to link `Notification` to `ApplicationUser` using foreign key. Like

```
public class Notification
{
    //rest of properties

    //change int to whatever type your primary key is in 
    //ApplicationUser class. I have Guid for example.
    public int ApplicationUser AssociatedUserId {get;set;}
}
```

Then try modifying configuration like this:

```
   modelBuilder.Entity<Notification>()
        .HasRequired(c => c.AssociatedUser)
        .WithMany(c => c.Notifications)
        .HasForeignKey(n=>n.AssociatedUserId);
```

Comment: What error did you get now? post the error details, that may help to pinpoint the actual issue. Is `ApplicationUser` also configured in same `DbContext` class?

Comment: The error i get is on the line : > UserManager.Update(addedUser);
It says entity framework constraints violation, the multiplicity of role (Notification_AssociatedUser_Target) of the relation (Qwirk.Models.Notification_AssociatedUser) is 1 or 0..1
As i said before it seems like when i instanciate a new notification the application just persists change and already creates the row on the notification table, so as a matter of effect, once i try to add that instance of notification to the user "addedUser" it seems that it tries to create another row on the notification table wich causes problems